# Equality in Ocaml hashtables

Tags: hashtable, ocaml, equality

Are there hashtables in Ocaml that use `==` instead of `=` when testing for equality of keys? 
For example:

```
# type foo = A of int;;
# let a = A(1);;
# let b = A(1);;
# a == b;;
- : bool = false
# a = b;;
- : bool = true
# let h = Hashtbl.create 8;;
# Hashtbl.add h a 1;;
# Hashtbl.add h b 2;;
# Hashtbl.find h a;;
- : int = 2
# Hashtbl.find h b;;
- : int = 2
```

I'd like a hashtable that can distinguish between `a` and `b`. Is that possible?

Comment: This kind of hash comparison is a little bit fragile when used with immutable values, as in your example.  The documents say the result of (==) is implementation dependent in that case: see the [Pervasives module under **Comparisons**](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html).  In theory the compiler or runtime can cause any two equal immutable values to be physically equal if they wish.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield The compiler or runtime may also cause values that you would expect to be physically equal to be different, and that's not theoretical: `let test x = let t = Array.make 1 x in x == t.(0) ;; test 1.0 ;;` computes `false`. The multi-thread GC for Caml that only exists on paper may also duplicate immutable values.

Comment: Thanks, these are very interesting examples, though I think OP is more concerned with the other side of the coin.  You can't depend on immutable values having unique physical identities (a != b) unless they're not equal (a <> b).  The usual solution (or, the one I have used) is to keep a unique identifier in your values.  This also helps with the hashing, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use custom hashtables:

```
module H = Hashtbl.Make(struct
  type t = foo
  let equal = (==)
  let hash = Hashtbl.hash
end)
```

And then use `H` instead of `Hashtbl` in your code.

Comment: when I paste this in the Ocaml's toploop, I get a syntax error (the last closing parenthesis is underlined).

Comment: missing the closing `end` to the `stuct` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

The solution in Thomas and cago's answers is functionally correct. One issue that may trouble you if you use their solution as-is is that you will get more collisions than expected if you hash many keys that are equal for `(=)` and different for `(==)`. Indeed, all keys that are equal for `(=)` have the same hash for `Hashtbl.hash`, and end up in the same bucket, where they are they recognized as different (since you asked for `(==)` to be used as equality function) and create different bindings. In the worst cases, the hash-table will behave with the same complexity as an association list (which, by the way, is another data structure that you could be using, and then you wouldn't have to worry about providing a hash function).

If you can accept the key of a value changing occasionally (and therefore the value being impossible to retrieve from the hash-table, since the binding is then in the wrong bucket), you can use the following low-level function as hash:

```
external address_of_value: 'a -> int = "address_of_value"
```

Implemented in C as:

```
#include "caml/mlvalues.h"

value address_of_value(value v)
{
  return (Val_long(((unsigned long)v)/sizeof(long)));
}
```

You would then use:

```
module H = Hashtbl.Make(struct
  type t = foo 
  let equal = (==) 
  let hash = address_of_value
end);;
```

Comment: The fact that equal (=) values will hash to the same bucket is a real problem.  If you're planning to put more than a few equal (but non-physically-equal) values in your hash table you'll see very poor performance unless you use a different hash function.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757509/stackoverflow-with-specialized-hashtbl-via-hashtbl-make

Comment: In older OCaml versions (I don't know if that's changed recently), only a minor GC or a compaction could move a block, so hashing on the pointer was safe if you turned off compaction and forced a minor GC before hashing. Not that I'd recommend that in a program you want to maintain.

Comment: @Gilles That is still the case. I almost pointed this information out, but then reflected that I was probably already being more technical than the OP desired. Some GCs have pinning, but that feels like the wrong tool for this problem. (==)-hashtables could be implemented by keeping minor objects separate from major ones and rehashing only these as necessary. It would still be necessary either to turn off compaction or to rehash each time one occurs.